# MVC Bundle Minification returns 404 with Umbraco 7.2.1

Tags: model-view-controller, bundling-and-minification, umbraco7

I'm unable to work out why i'm getting the 404, if i turn

> BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

then everything works OK, but set it to

> BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

then I get

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I cannot work this out and it only happens for css, js bundle works ok any help appreciated.

I'm Using VS2015 and Umbraco 7.2.1

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace Web.UI
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                         "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
                      "~/Content/PagedList.css",
                      "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }
    }
}

using System.Web.Optimization;
using Umbraco.Core;

namespace Web.UI
{
    public class ApplicationEvents : ApplicationEventHandler
    {
        protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
        {
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}

<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/bundles/" />


@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@ViewBag.Description" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10" style="text-align: center">
               <img src="../../Images/Sitelogo.png" alt="Logo" width="300" />              
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu1" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home">&nbsp;</i></a>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-menubuilder">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container bottomPadding">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <footer role="navigation">
                    <p>@Umbraco.RenderMacro("CopyrightDate")</p>
                </footer>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @RenderSection("datepicker",false)

</body>
</html>
```

Namespace

```
<add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
```

added to web.config in Views Folder

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to my problem, the following link explains http://letswritecode.net/articles/using-the-umbraco-client-dependency-framework-to-bundle-and-minify/